# Solution to save Jmeter Dashboard reports to Confluence

Tags: jmeter, confluence

Need a solution to save the Jmeter Dashboard report in Confluence

I am using Jmeter 5.1 and at the end of the test run, I get a nice graphical Dashboard report containing throughput, error rate, Response time etc. I need to upload this report to confluence so that everyone has access to it. How can this be done? I see that the Dashboard uses the .jtl file, so want to know what files need to be packaged and uploaded for the report to be displayed correctly in Confluence

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_gui) report is generating also HTML, You can do i manually

> You can generate the HTML report using menu item Tools → Generate HTML report

[image]

Comment: At the end of my test run, I do have the index.html, .jtl and .log files generated and that index.html is what I use to view the Dashboard report. But it's just not enough to save that index.html to my confluence since that report is also dependent on the .jtl file as far as I can see. But I am not too sure what else it requires to generate that Dashboard report, so that I can compress them and save it to my confluence for future reference