# How to save charts from dashboard report (JMeter)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

There is an answer how to generate JMeter report: [How do I generate a Dashboard Report in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263768/how-do-i-generate-a-dashboard-report-in-jmeter)

And there is a question w/out accepted answer [Solution to save Jmeter Dashboard reports to Confluence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188695/solution-to-save-jmeter-dashboard-reports-to-confluence).

Although ultimately I now need to put info in Confluence, I want at least to be able to copy charts/graphs one by one, but although in both Chrome and Firefox I do have context menu of saving a picture ('Save image'), however resulting image looks empty in both of browsers. How can I save chart from HTML report to image?

Below is start of hexdump of one png file (they all come 32Kb size).

```
0000000 211   P   N   G  \r  \n 032  \n  \0  \0  \0  \r   I   H   D   R
0000010  \0  \0  \b 213  \0  \0 003      \b 006  \0  \0  \0   ?   ?   p
0000020  \n  \0  \0      \0   I   D   A   T   x   ^   ?   ?   A 001  \0
0000030  \0  \b 002   1   ?   _   ?       7 033   0   |   ?   s 004  \b
0000040 020       @ 200  \0 001 002 004  \b 020       @ 200  \0 001 002
0000050 004  \b 020       @ 200  \0 001 002 004  \b 020       @ 200  \0
0000060 001 002 031 201   e 222  \n   J 200  \0 001 002 004  \b 020    
0000070   @ 200  \0 001 002 004  \b 020       @ 200  \0 001 002 004  \b
0000080 020       @ 200  \0 001 002 004  \b 020       p   ?   " 236 200
0000090  \0 001 002 004  \b 020       @ 200  \0 001 002 004  \b 020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JMeterPluginsCMD](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)  to produce a image from report

> There is small command-line utility for generating graphs out of JTL files. It behave just like right-click context menu on all graphs. The tool can generate PNG
>
> Generating PNG:
>
> ```
> JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png test.png --input-jtl results.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime --width 800 --height 600
> ```

In order to generate graphs using that plugin you most probably need also to install `jpgc - Standard Set` plugin and `graph`-s plugins (in plugins manager in JMeter on available page search for `graph` and install what suits needed charts description).

Parameter `--plugin-type` to choose graph type may not always be made of same wording as graphs names in HTLM report, see list of parameters on [JMeterPluginsCMD](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)  page along with list of parameters to customise looks of graphs.

Comment: It need as input name of each graph? if so I can of cause write command file with several invocations...

Comment: I now got error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.ResponseTimesOverTimeGui` caused by `kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:227)`

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov Missing plugin see http://www.jmeter-archive.org/The-error-when-executing-JMeterPluginsCMD-Command-Line-Tool-td5725056.html

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov can you ask a new question with more details of versions and exception?

Answer (score 2):

The charts are not normal [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) they reside in [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) tag

[image]

if you really want to proceed this way you could locate the `canvas` element you want to save and invoke [toDataUrl()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) function on it like:

```
document.getElementById('responseTimesOverTime').getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL()
```

[image]

Once done you will get so called [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) in form of `data:image/png;base64,...............` text as the output.

If you put this text into your browser URL area the image will open:

[image]

And this will be "real" image which can be saved.

An easier option would be using service like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) which can generate PDF reports out of the .jtl results files which can be added to the Confluence via the [PDF Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/pdf-macro-375849180.html)